How to access ipc on host from a docker container and keep internal ipc private?
An application let's say A (which is made of several processes) uses a lot of hard coded filenames for message queues, shared memory and semaphores. The application is proprietary, should be run as root, and there is not much documentation about it. However, hard coded names make it impossible to run several applications on the same host at the same time, so docker is used to isolate each application. So far so good.
Now, another application, let's say B, running on the host needs to create new message queues/shared memory/semaphores to communicate with each A's apps in their containers without interfering with their internals ipc.
--ipc=host is not sufficient here because of conflicting ipc names for A's internals.
I am working on a Debian host to make some experiments (i am not a docker expert) and trying to focus on message queues first. For example, using bind mounts does not work as expected :
docker run -ti --privileged --mount type=bind,src=/dev/mqueue/mq_test,dst=/dev/mqueue/mq_test ubuntu:v1 bash

/dev/mqueue/mq_test is created on the host by B and from the bash in the container, i can see that the mqueue filesystem seems to be mounted correctly :
mqueue on /dev/mqueue/mq_test type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)

and i can even do :
root@e39210cd6fa3:/# cat /dev/mqueue/mq_test 
QSIZE:18         NOTIFY:0     SIGNO:0     NOTIFY_PID:0

18 bytes were sent from B in the host to the queue but for an unknown reason, i cannot simply read them with this small test program from within the container :
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    mode_t mode = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR;
    mqd_t mq_fd = mq_open("/mq_test", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, mode, NULL);

    if (mq_fd == -1) {

        perror("mq_open");
        return -1;
    }

    char buf[10] = {0};

    struct mq_attr attr;
    
    if (mq_getattr(mq_fd, &attr) == -1) {
    
        perror("mq_getattr");
        return -1;
    }

    if (mq_receive(mq_fd, buf, attr.mq_msgsize, NULL) == -1) {

        perror("mq_receive");
        return -1;
    } else
        printf("buf = %s", buf);

    puts("\n");

    return 0;
}

The program remains blocked in mq_receive whereas, the same program compiled on the host can consume bytes correctly (i don't suspect the problem comes from the test program but more from a wrong docker configuration or options).
Is there a technique or even a workaround to achieve this with docker ? Basically, i would like to share message queues created in the host with the container but message queue created in the container should remain invisible to the host.
Thank you.

Do you have the source code to the proprietary app? Can you rebuild/tweak it if necessary?

Yes, it might be possible if necessary even though that should be best avoided. Any idea ?

Probably not a good use of containers, given the need to access via B. Given that you can change the source (or even if you can't), instead of using containers, I would create wrapper functions for mq_open et. al. in a shared library that morph the filenames. That is, /mq_test --> /uid_pid_mqtest (e.g.). The wrapper changes the names on the fly. The unique prefix could come from a command line arg or environment variable. The mechanism would be similar to how valgrind invokes a program under LD_PRELOAD

That's a good hint. I am actually already using LD_PRELOAD to solve another problem.
